# Deriving a standard deviation of a random variable using correlated other random variables

Tags: correlation, variance, covariance

Consider three random variables: $$u_1, u_2, u_3 \;\; with \;\; E[u_j]=0 \;\; and\;\;  Var[u_j]=\sigma^2_j\;\;for\;\;j=1,2,3$$
Here, we know the values $\sigma_1,\;\sigma_2$ and $\rho_{13},\;\rho_{23}$ where $\rho_{j3} = corr(u_j,\;u_3)$, but we do not have the standard deviation $\sigma_3$.

Can you come up with a combination of $\sigma_1,\;\sigma_2,\;\rho_{13},$ and $\rho_{23}$ that is equal to $\sigma_3$?

In my trials, we can show that:
$$\rho_{13}\sigma_1-\rho_{23}\sigma_2=\frac{E[u_1u_3]}{\sigma_3} - \frac{E[u_2u_3]}{\sigma_3}=\frac{E[u_1u_3]-E[u_2u_3]}{\sigma_3}$$
thus, if we can know $Cov(u_1,u_3)=E[u_1u_3]$ and $Cov(u2,u3)=E[u_2u_3]$, we get $\sigma_3$.

However, I have no idea how to derive the covariance.

Do you have any good idea to derive $\sigma_3$?

Comment: Since $\sigma_3=\rho_{23}/(Cov(u_2,u_3)\sigma_2)$ it would be enough to know $Cov(u_2,u_3)$, but I do not see how that covariance would follow from the remaining two equations determining a correlation matrix.

Comment: If you *could* find a value for $\sigma_3,$ the fact that $u_1,u_2,\lambda u_3$ would satisfy all the same conditions for any $\lambda\gt 0$ shows that your value is determined only up to an arbitrary positive multiple: in other words, it isn't restricted at all.